# Eigen syntax highlighting

Tags: c++, vim, eigen, youcompleteme

Does anyone know how to enable syntax highlighting for YouCompleteMe in Vim for the Eigen library in c++?

I've tried looking around the internet and cannot find anyone who has done it.

Comment: Doesn't [syntastic](https://github.com/vim-syntastic/syntastic) work?

Comment: It might, but I want to use YouCompleteMe